# Copy item from one listbox to another on double click. Doubleclick event not fired. Winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, double-click

I am quite new to Winform dev. I have two list boxes. When the user double clicks an item in the first listbox, I want this to be copied to the second list box. The problem is that my double click method never gets fired.
here's my code:

```
//here I register the event
this.fieldsArea.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(fieldsArea_MouseDoubleClick);
```

Then here is the double click method:

```
    private void fieldsArea_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("from method");
        int index = fieldsArea.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        string s = fieldsArea.Items[index].ToString();

        selectedFieldsArea.Items.Add(s);
    }
```

So I want the element from fieldsArea to be copied to selectedFieldsArea... The messagebox never shows and in debug I see that I never enter this method... 
Am I missing something here?

ps: I have drag drop implemented which works well.

**UPDATE**: The problem comes from the MouseDown event also being implemented. So here's my mousedown event.

```
private void fieldsArea_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fieldsArea.Items.Count == 0)
            return;
        int index = fieldsArea.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        string s = fieldsArea.Items[index].ToString();
        DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s,
            DragDropEffects.All);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have other Mouse event like `MouseClick` `MouseDown` event registered, which could interfere with `MouseDoubleclick` event.

**Update**:

Add following code in your `MouseDown` event handler, you can check if it is a double-click first.

```
if(e.Clicks>1)
{
   int index = fieldsArea.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
   string s = fieldsArea.Items[index].ToString();
   selectedFieldsArea.Items.Add(s); 
}
```

so here is your new handler:

```
private void fieldsArea_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (fieldsArea.Items.Count == 0)
            return;
  int index = fieldsArea.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
  string s = fieldsArea.Items[index].ToString();

  if(e.Clicks>1)
  {          
       selectedFieldsArea.Items.Add(s); 
  }
  else
  {
        DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s,
        DragDropEffects.All);
  }
}
```

Comment: I do for my drag drop... Is it not possible to have drag drop and double click at the same time? ps: I just commented out my mousedown and it solved the issue...

Comment: @nche, It is possible, just post your mousedown event, and we can have a look for you.

Comment: I just added it to the question

Answer (score 2):

> ps: I have drag drop implemented which works well.

That means probably that you have registered a `MouseDown` event, which interfere with the `MouseDoubleclick`.

Just for testing purpose, try to delete the Drag&Drop implementation ( unregister the `MouseDown` event) and then the `MouseDoubleclick` should work.

Comment: I did and it works. So I guess I'll update my question to ask how to implement the two.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have either "MouseClick/MouseDown" event or "SelectedIndexChanged" event, these events resist to get fire of "MouseDoubleclick" event, so you need to handle them properly. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I didn't get the update before my post, so please take it easy, thanks for your time.